# Calling a JavaScript function inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript and jQuery. My main file has `My.js` and Ajax.

#### My.js

```
function build_one(){
    alert("inside build_one");
}
```

#### My main file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ..

    // Here I want to make call function defined in My.js build_one()
    ..

    // Here is the Ajax call

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data:'id='+id  ,
        success: function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        }
    });

    ...

</script>
```

How do I make the build_one() function call before the Ajax function?

Comment: Am I missing something in the question ? Looking at the couple of answers, I think not. I am really amazed at the simplicity of the question, coming from someone using jQuery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="My.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    build_one();

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:'id='+id  ,
            success: function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
            }
         });
</script>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to say the exact same thing. Even the code is the same.

Comment: Using language attribute in the script tag is not required and in fact is non-standardized

Answer (score 5):

First you have to import your file before calling the function using the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="My.js"></script>
```

Now you can call your function where ever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my question. :) The function that's defined in another file needs to be called outside of jQuery and assigned to a variable if you want to use the results inside jQuery.
Hope that tidbit helps somebody.